# Write data in existing file Yii2 framework

Tags: php, file, yii2, file-writing

I am trying to write data in a json file from yii2 framework. It's returning error failed to open stream. My code is given below.

```
$productjson = json_encode($value);
echo $jsonfile=Yii::$app->view->theme->baseUrl.'/assets/json/aresult.json';
$fp = fopen($jsonfile, 'w+');
fwrite($fp, $productjson);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Is destination folder writable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the right way to specify the path

```
 $productjson = json_encode($value);
 echo $jsonfile= Yii::getAlias('@webroot/assets/aresult.json');
 $fp = fopen($jsonfile, 'w+');
 fwrite($fp, $productjson);
 fclose($fp);
```

[And yii2 has a class to work with json](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-json.html)

Comment: Thanks @gud3. Working perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Your `$jsonfile` variable contains the file URL, while it should contain your file's path in the server. Check the [predefined aliases](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-aliases.html#predefined-aliases).

For example:

```
$jsonfile=Yii::getAlias('@app').'/assets/json/aresult.json';
```

Comment: Thanks @gmc for trying to help me. Your example is also working but I am sorry for not to checked as solved.